# Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSView)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm working on Xcode 10.0 - macOS 10.14 (Mojave). I was doing an app for my school project that shows the list of movies in rows with their posters and rating stars. Whenever I'm trying to start my application, I'm getting errors:

> [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)

But it seems that is the system's problem (as I read on Apple forums)... And the second error:

> Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSView): missing setter or instance variable

Are these errors somewhat connected? I was looking at the .xib file, trying to set the Main.storyboard as Main Interface but there I have empty view... With the .xib file I have nothing - app starts, but only these two errors show up. Here's the code:

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "NSObject+IntengineMovieData.h"
#import "NSObject+IntengineMovieDoc.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

    if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"MoviesColumn"]) {
        IntengineMovieDoc *movieDoc = [self.movies objectAtIndex:row];
        cellView.imageView.image = movieDoc.thumbImage;
        cellView.textField.stringValue = movieDoc.data.title;
        return cellView;
    }
    return cellView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.movies count];
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NSObject+IntengineMovieDoc.h"
#include "MasterViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MasterViewController *masterViewController;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]
                                 initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    IntengineMovieDoc *movie1 = [[IntengineMovieDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Godfather" rating:5 thumbImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TheGodfatherThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TheGodfather.jpg"]];

    IntengineMovieDoc *movie2 = [[IntengineMovieDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tree of Life" rating:4 thumbImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TreeOfLifeThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TreeOfLife.jpg"]];

    IntengineMovieDoc *movie3 = [[IntengineMovieDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"Taxi Driver" rating:5 thumbImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TaxiDriverThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TaxiDriver.jpg"]];

    NSMutableArray *movies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: movie1, movie2, movie3, nil];
    self.masterViewController.movies = movies;

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    self.masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
@end
```

---

EDIT 1: Ok, it seems that I have one extra outlet in `Referencing Outlets` in View Panel. I didn't add that, but after remove this link, app won't show either. Now it shows only this error:

> [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create an `IBOutlet` for your view controller since you are instantiating a new instance anyway inside your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Additionaly, you should make your `masterViewController` as the `rootViewController` of your window like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.masterViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You might have to create a new window first:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: As before - nothing shows. I have to replace UIWindow for NSWindow, because it's not iOS, but still nothing happened at all.

Comment: Damn! I mistook it to be iOS. Apologies.

Comment: No problem. Check my edit, I solved one problem, but the app didn't showed yet...